# Spring Integration - Best Practices for Sanity Check

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Are there any best practices to follow for determining that a spring integration channel has data regularly flowing through it?  I have need to check on processes from time to time and I'd like to include this sort of check as part of my regular sanity checks, along with process and connectivity-type checks like JMS readers/writers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to use [JMX Metrics](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#jmx-channel-features)

There is just enough to enable JMX export for Spring Integration components:

```
<int-jmx:mbean-export/>
```

From other side you always can implement your own statistics with custom `ChannelInterceptor` and inject it to the `<channel>` definition.